# Why were the flags (as obsolete) on these comments marked as declined?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

[image]

I flagged both of them as obsolete as they both are not fruitful any more. But my flags are declined.

Does this community have some other rules in this case? I often do it in stackoverflow and have never had the flags declined.

The comments are [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172461/how-to-prove-that-frac-leftx-i-barx-rights-leq-fracn-1-sqrtn/172466#comment325860_172466) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172461/how-to-prove-that-frac-leftx-i-barx-rights-leq-fracn-1-sqrtn/172466#comment325896_172466).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I appreciate your interest in helping curate this site and hope you will continue to do so.

Since I declined the second flag, I can explain. It was a simple mistake. The system does not clearly present a flagged comment to the reviewer: it shows the whole sequence of comments and attempts to bring the flagged one to the top of the screen. Due to ongoing re-display of marked-up material above it, the positioning is sometimes incorrect. In this case the comment presented to me appeared to be "Will, but tomorrow, now I have to prepare tomorrows class." I could see why this might be flagged as "too chatty," but nevertheless it was still current, and so I declined it.

If I had been the one to field the first flag, I might also have declined it.  It is still relevant to a key issue that initially confounded several respondents.  When an action may be difficult to reverse--such as removing a comment--I prefer to take it only when it seems clear it will improve the site and is consistent with our policies.  When there is some doubt, it is best to leave things as they are.